# How to add company name using wix installer

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5, wix3.7

I want to add company name using wix installer but didt see any option to give that. ONly I can able to give Manufacturer

<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Manufacturer="XXXxxxxxxx"

OUr company whitelist software based on company name and previously we used windows installer, now changed to WIX based installer. Is there ay way to give company name using wix installer

On selecting software it shows Authors:XXXxxxxxxx (wix baed installer)

But on selecting WIndows based installer it shows Company: XXXxxxxxxx

Comment: Can you add some screen shots of the difference? Are these the file properties seen in Windows Explorer or are you looking inside the MSI using Orca? Are you signing the file with a digital certificate?

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to set the COMPANYNAME property in the MSI. If this is what you're trying to do then set the Manufacturer value in the Package node. I'm confused though because this is exactly what you posted in your question.

Comment: @Doc unlikely. COMPANYNAME is the value of the organization doing the installation not who wrote the installation.  It's also a public property that can be passed at the commandline so this wouldn't make for effective whitelisting at all.

Comment: I am seeing while selecting the MSI using mouse pointer, I already added Manufacture value as company name but on selecting, instead of Company name author is showing the manufacturer value. No where COmpany name is present. ITs having only TITLE, AUTHOR, SUBJECT and ITEM TYPE

Comment: Ack! I totally bone that one @ChristopherPainter. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine any effective whitelisting that doesn't rely on digital signatures.  You probably need to sign the MSI with a trusted cert.  Since you say "our company" I assume this is an internal IT product so whoever owns the whitelisting process should be able to tell you exactly what is required at your organization.